# js obj supposedly passed by reference, but appears cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have learned that objects in javascript is passed by reference, so if I delete one, they will both be inaccessible.

Now,

```
var self = self.parent.modules[moduleId].slideshow;

delete self.parent.modules[moduleId].slideshow; //remove the module object from the JSON

console.error('deleted self. it is now:');                
console.error(self.parent.modules[moduleId].slideshow);
```

that console prints undefined, as expected. However, if I do this:

```
console.error('deleted self. it is now:');                
console.error(self);
```

It still has the object to present me with, as if it was actually cloned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deleted the *property* not the value that property referenced.

Other references that value are unaffected.

Comment: Oh... how can I also delete the value referenced by the property? see that is what I intended to do.

Comment: Only by deleting all references to it.

Comment: could I set it to null first and then delete the refrence? For a similar effect..

Comment: No, you'd be changing the property's value from a reference to X to a reference to null. It wouldn't affect X.